# ntiles over columns in python using R's "mutate(across(cols = ..."

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

In `R` I have some data:

```
library(tidyverse)

d = data.frame(
  "A" = c(0.1, 0.76, 0.54, 0.79, 0.28),
    "B" = c(3, 2, 4, 3, 4),
    "C" = c(2, 2, 7, 3, 4),
    "D" = c(4, 3, 6, 12, 7)
)
```

Where I can apply across each column a computation to compute the `ntiles`:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(),
              .fns = ~ ntile(., 5),
              .names = "{.col}_ntiles")
)
```

Which gives me the following output - **Desired output**:

```
     A B C  D A_ntiles B_ntiles C_ntiles D_ntiles
1 0.10 3 2  4        1        2        1        2
2 0.76 2 2  3        4        1        2        1
3 0.54 4 7  6        3        4        5        3
4 0.79 3 3 12        5        3        3        5
5 0.28 4 4  7        2        5        4        4
```

I am trying to do this same task in Python.

I managed to get as far as the following:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0.1, 0.76, 0.54, 0.79, 0.28],
                   "B":[3, 2, 4, 3, 4],
                   "C":[2, 2, 7, 3, 4],
                   "D":[4, 3, 6, 12, 7]})

d.quantile([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8], axis = 0)
```

Which gives me:

```
    A   B   C   D
0.2     0.244   2.8     2.0     3.8
0.4     0.436   3.0     2.6     5.2
0.6     0.628   3.4     3.4     6.4
0.8     0.766   4.0     4.6     8.0
```

However, I would like to obtain which rank category each `ntile` belongs to - just as in the `R` example using `A_ntiles`, `B_ntiles` ... `D_ntiles`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check with `rank`

```
out = d.join(d.rank(method='first').add_suffix('_ntile').astype(int))

out
Out[92]: 
      A  B  C   D  A_ntile  B_ntile  C_ntile  D_ntile
0  0.10  3  2   4        1        2        1        2
1  0.76  2  2   3        4        1        2        1
2  0.54  4  7   6        3        4        5        3
3  0.79  3  3  12        5        3        3        5
4  0.28  4  4   7        2        5        4        4
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

```
rank_quantile = lambda x: pd.qcut(x, q=5, labels=False, duplicates='drop')
out = pd.concat([d, d.apply(rank_quantile).add(1).add_suffix('_nqtiles')], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
      A  B  C   D  A_nqtiles  B_nqtiles  C_nqtiles  D_nqtiles
0  0.10  3  2   4          1          2          1          2
1  0.76  2  2   3          4          1          1          1
2  0.54  4  7   6          3          4          4          3
3  0.79  3  3  12          5          2          2          5
4  0.28  4  4   7          2          4          3          4
```

---

**Old answer**

Use `rank` with `method='first'` then concatenate your dataframe:

```
out = pd.concat([d, d.rank(method='first').astype(int).add_suffix('_ntile')], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
      A  B  C   D  A_ntile  B_ntile  C_ntile  D_ntile
0  0.10  3  2   4        1        2        1        2
1  0.76  2  2   3        4        1        2        1
2  0.54  4  7   6        3        4        5        3
3  0.79  3  3  12        5        3        3        5
4  0.28  4  4   7        2        5        4        4
```

Comment: Thanks (to everyone who answered) - however, the both answers (as far as I am aware) ranks the data from `1 - nrow()` - in this example I have 5 rows so I have rankings from `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` but on larger data frames I will have rankings `1, 2, 3, ..., 678, 679, 680 ... ` - however I only want the rankings from `1:5`. (i.e. to allow for groups of ranks). So the data may look like `1 , 1, 1, 2, 2,  3, 3, 3 ... 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5`

Comment: I "think" this gets what I want for a given column `d = pd.qcut(ntile_data['Fuente.de.ingreso..salario'], q=5, duplicates='drop', retbins=True, labels=False)`

Comment: I updated my answer with a slight edit to yours. Can you check it please? I don't understand why with R, you have for B, the first 3 -> 2 and the second 3 -> 3? This is the same quantile?

Answer (score 1):

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), a pandas wrapper, we are able to do it similarly as we did in R:

```py
>>> from datar.all import c, tibble, mutate, across, everything, row_number
>>> 
>>> d = tibble(
...     A=c(0.1, 0.76, 0.54, 0.79, 0.28),
...     B=c(3, 2, 4, 3, 4),
...     C=c(2, 2, 7, 3, 4),
...     D=c(4, 3, 6, 12, 7),
... )
>>> 
>>> 
>>> d >> mutate(across(everything(), row_number, _names="{_col}_ntiles"))
          A       B       C       D  A_ntiles  B_ntiles  C_ntiles  D_ntiles
  <float64> <int64> <int64> <int64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64>
0      0.10       3       2       4       1.0       2.0       1.0       2.0
1      0.76       2       2       3       4.0       1.0       2.0       1.0
2      0.54       4       7       6       3.0       4.0       5.0       3.0
3      0.79       3       3      12       5.0       3.0       3.0       5.0
4      0.28       4       4       7       2.0       5.0       4.0       4.0
```